# How to change the target platform in VS2017 on the command line

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am trying to migrate a project from VS2010 to VS2017. The project utilizes Makefile (for a number of reasons). So I compile with CL.exe

The problem is that CL.exe from VS2017 compiles my sources as if the target platform is Windows 10 and tries including headers from UCRT:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory
```

This file (`corecrt.h`) is part of the Windows 10 SDK and UCRT.

I get this problem even if I change the environment to use Windows 8.1 SDK instead of 10:

```
INCLUDE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\atlmfc\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\crt\src\stl;"

LIB="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\Lib\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\lib\x64\store;"
```

There must be some switch or some other way to tell CL.exe that I want to use Windows 8.1 SDK or that I want to target Windows 7/8.x.

Does anybody knows how this works?

Comment: stuck on the same thing, have you figure out the solution?